# "openssl crl" verify gives "Error getting CRL issuer certificate"

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, openssl, crl, pem

File A - This is my CRL File - http://pastebin.com/yvstfPTD

File B - It's signed by this cert - http://pastebin.com/T1pXZSat

File C - The CRL signing cert has been issued by this CA http://pastebin.com/Q82PZCh1

File B & C are in directory `dir1`

When I issue command

```
openssl crl -in A -CApath dir1
```

I get the error

```
Error getting CRL issuer certificate
```

This is a vague error message.

How do I figure our what's the problem here?

All files are in PEM format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR: IT'S THE WRONG CERT**

The issuer name in that CRL is

```
$ openssl crl -in file0 -noout -issuer
issuer=/C=IN/O=Gujarat Narmada Valley Fertilizers Company Ltd./OU=Certifying Authority/postalCode=380054/ST=Gujarat/street=Bodakdev, S G Road, Ahmedabad/houseIdentifier=301, GNFC Infotower/CN=(n)Code Solutions CA 2011-1
```

The subject name in your purported signing cert is

```
$ openssl x509 -in file1 -noout -subject
subject= /C=IN/O=Gujarat Narmada Valley Fertilizers and Chemicals Limited/OU=Certifying Authority/postalCode=380054/ST=Gujarat/street=Bodakdev, S G Road, Ahmedabad/houseIdentifier=301, GNFC Infotower/CN=(n)Code Solutions CA 2014
```

These are not the same. The first one is 'Fertilizers **Company Ltd.**' while the second one is 'Fertilizers **and Chemicals Limited**' and the year (or year-like number) in CN is different.

In addition, if I ignore this mismatch and check manually, the RSA signature in the CRL does not 'decrypt' (more accurately, recover) to valid PKCS1-v1_5 padding using the key in the purported signing certificate. This means it was signed with a different keypair, which must have a different cert.

Comment: ` check manually, the RSA signature in the CRL does not 'decrypt' (more accurately, recover) to valid PKCS1-v1_5 padding using the key in the purported signing certificate.` - how does one do that - can you give the openssl commands?